# What order for uses in interface?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Whilst moving some applications from Delphi XE2 to XE5 I've noticed that there are a number of units listed which are no longer needed.

This is turn lead me to tidying up the **uses** section of the **interface** which leads to my question.

Is there a recommended order for units in the interface?  I know they are loaded in *reverse* order, but should I be organising them by Usnit Scope.

For example should *MyCompany.** be listed at the start or the end? Should I place the *Vcl.** before the *System.**

**update**

In general I will include my Units in the **implementation** rather than **interface**.  I'm grasping more about whether there is a hierarchy to Delphi's own units...

For example I have encountered one issue where listing the Windows unit *before* System.SysUtils changes the version of DeleteFile that is used...

**Explicit Question**

Should the order of uses be

Winapi*, System.*, Vcl.*,  or the reverse?

Comment: *I know they are loaded in reverse order*. You think you know that, but you are wrong. They are processed in order. If there are name collisions, last imported wins. I always list uses low-level first, high-level last. So, RTL first, then VCL, then your units. And your code will surely have hierarchy. Respect that too. But it's for you to work out what rules you want to follow. How can we answer if we don't know the impact that order changes have on your code base?

Comment: David - that's the nub of what I was trying to ask :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some risks associated with uses list refactoring:

- Later used units will override symbols (`methods`, `classes`, `vars`, `consts`, ...) of units used earlier (scoping).

  This can introduce (more or less) sublte bugs into your program.
- Reordering units can change the order in which `intialization` and `finalization` sections are run.

There are also some advantages:

- Faster compiling speed
- Smaller executables (Only if any removed units had `initialization` or `finalization`)
- Avoiding / Preventing uses circles (although uses circles are often a sign of a sub optimal OOP design)

Having said that and after your question update:

I tend to do the same thing that David already wrote: Order the units from low level to high level.

There are tools that can help you with finding unused units and also arranging the used ones in the best order. ([Peganza Icarus / PascalAnalyzer](http://www.peganza.com/) and [ModelMaker](http://www.modelmakertools.com/))

It's hard to say what the compiler really does (especially since there are now multiple compilers), but putting units with the least dependencies first should make it easier for the compiler to build the dependency tree.

Comment: For removing unused units, cnPack also has an excellent automatic tool.  Although I like the way Pascal Analyser tells you which units can be shifted from interface to implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Read http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Programs_and_Units and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_Namespaces_with_Delphi articles.These 2 articles are explaining exactly what you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

The TMS Software, author of many components for Delphi - recommend on their [blogpost](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=447) the following order:

```
uses  
  // 1. fpc/lazarus/delphi units,  
  // 2. 3rd units,  
  // 3. my open source units,  
  // 4. project units
```

It is actually the best option in my opinion. You can change the order. Important is only to remember that when the function/class name will be used in more than unit, the last one unit will be used.